# how to pass stdout data to a variable c?

Tags: c

I am making an algorithm that takes the data from a file according to the number entered and gives me some information, I would like to take this information and transfer it to a variable or write it straight to a file

the ideal plan would be to go directly to a file
what I've done so far but to no avail

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXC 1024   
#define MAXN  128

int main (int argc, char **argv) {


    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("Test.txt","r");



    if (!(fp = fopen ("Test.txt", "r"))) {
       printf("ERROR");
        return 1;
    }

    for (;;) { 
        char buf[MAXC] = "";
        int id = 0, inputid = 0;

        rewind (fp);   
        fputs("enter ID: ", stdout);
        fflush (stdout);   

        if (!fgets (buf, MAXC, stdin) || strcmp (buf, "quit\n") == 0)
            break;


        if (sscanf (buf, "%d", &inputid) != 1) {
            fputs ("error: invalid integer input.\n", stderr);
            break;
        }

        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp))  
            if (sscanf (buf, "ID : %d", &id) == 1 && id == inputid)
                break;

        if (id != inputid) {  
            fputs ("error: ID not found.\n", stderr);
            continue;
        }

        FILE * fp1;
        fp1 = ("Test1.txt","a");
        while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && *buf != '=')
            fputs (buf, stdout);
            fprintf(fp1,buf,stdout);
            fclose(fp1);
    }

    fclose (fp);   

    return 0;
}
```

the contents of file Test.txt is

```
ID : 2
Nome da Pizza : Gostosona
Ingredientes : Alho, Molho de Tomate, Carne Desfiada, Calabresa
Valor Grande R$: 26,99
Valor Broto R$: 18,00
==========================================
```

I read a few things about passing stdout content to a variable, but to no avail as well.

Comment: Why are you opening `Test.txt` twice without closing the first open?

Comment: is diferent files and diferent closing

Comment: Also `fp1 = ("Test1.txt","a");` is not opening a file but setting `fp1` to the pointer pointing at a non-modifiable char array `'a', '\0'`.

Comment: regarding: `fp1 = ("Test1.txt","a");`   This only assigns a pointer to some text.  What is actually needed is: `fp1 =  fopen("Test1.txt","a");` so it opens a file for 'append`.   when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, then call: `perror()` to output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`,  Then, since that error is not recoverable, call: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`.  Note: both `exit()` and EXIT_FAILURE are exposed by `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main (int argc, char **argv)`  Since the parameters are not used, the compiler will output two 'unused parameter' warning messages.  to avoid those messages, use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && *buf != '=')
            fputs (buf, stdout);
            fprintf(fp1,buf,stdout);
            fclose(fp1);`   The containment of statements after a `while()` statement only covers the first following statement.  Indenting the code is meaningless to the compiler.  Suggest using: `while (fgets (buf, MAXC, fp) && *buf != '=') {
            fputs (buf, stdout);
            fprintf(fp1,buf,stdout); }
            fclose(fp1);`  Notice the braces '{' and '}' to group the statements and only close the file once

Comment: regarding: `for (;;) { 
        ...
        rewind (fp);`  The result is the same part of the input file is re-read for each loop iteration, so the read `ID` never changes.  This is (probably) a logic error.

Comment: regarding: `        fclose(fp1);
    }

    fclose (fp);`   This is closing the 'fp' file on every iteration of the loop, but that file is never re-opened.  So the call to: `rewind(fp)` at the top of the loop will result in a runtime failure.

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("ERROR");`  Error messages should be meaningful and output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  Also, when the error message is from a C library function should also output to `stderr` the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror()` is made for this purpose.